# Como calcular o tempo do ponto A ao B?

Tags: python

Preciso fazer um controle de tempo que um caminhão demora de uma fábrica `X` ate uma revenda `Y`, além de calcular quanto tempo ele ficou nessa revenda.

Tenho dados do GPS e retirei informações que eram relevantes pois são muitos dados e ficaria muito lento usá-los. Minha tabela está da seguinte forma:

```
+----+------------------+-----------+---------------+
| ID |   DATA E HORA    |   LOCAL   | ENTRADA/SAIDA |
+----+------------------+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | 28/01/2017 07:27 | FABRICA   | Entrada       |
|  2 | 28/01/2017 09:00 | FABRICA   | Saida         |
|  3 | 29/01/2017 00:02 | REVENDA 1 | Entrada       |
|  4 | 29/01/2017 04:00 | REVENDA 1 | Saida         |
|  5 | 29/01/2017 08:00 | REVENDA 2 | Entrada       |
|  6 | 29/01/2017 10:00 | REVENDA 2 | Saida         |
|  7 | 29/01/2017 20:00 | FABRICA   | Entrada       |
|  8 | 29/01/2017 23:00 | FABRICA   | Saida         |
+----+------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Tenho que pegar um intervalo de dia/hora em que ele estava em uma revenda e fazer estes cálculos (saber quanto tempo ele ficou na revenda e quanto tempo ele demorou para chegar lá a partir da fabrica X).

O cálculo do tempo da revenda parece ser mais fácil (Saída **-** Entrada) o problema maior é o tempo  da fabrica até a revenda. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso (pode ser pela própria QUERY SQL se possível)

*PS: O modelo da tabela pode ser alterado, fiz dessa forma porque achei mais fácil de usar; Estou usando SQLite mas posso usar qualquer BD que seja como ele*

Obrigado.

Comment: A tabela tem uma chave ?

Comment: Tem, já adicionei no exemplo.

Comment: Veja se ajuda http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/555701-somar-diferenca-entra-varias-datas-e-horas/#entry2216634

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Observação 1**: A sua pergunta tem a tag [python](/questions/tagged/python), então vou responder com uma sugestão de como fazer isso usando o Python. Mas se
>   os seus dados estão mantidos em um banco de dados SQL, certamente é
>   muito melhor você já trazer os resultados filtrados (isto é, só a
>   sub-tabela com o percurso) ou, melhor ainda, já calcular isso
>   diretamente por lá (com uma *stored procedure*, por exemplo). Se não
>   sabe como montar uma *query* assim, abra outra pergunta e voltada à
>   SQL.
>
> **Observação 2**: Pra facilitar eu coloquei os seus dados em um arquivo CSV local, e os li com a função [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) do Pandas. No
>   seu caso, basta trocar pela função [`read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_sql.html). Esse é o arquivo
>   CSV utilizado:
>
> ```
> ID,DATA E HORA,LOCAL,ENTRADA/SAIDA
> 1,28/01/2017 07:27,FABRICA,Entrada
> 2,28/01/2017 09:00,FABRICA,Saida
> 3,29/01/2017 00:02,REVENDA 1,Entrada
> 4,29/01/2017 04:00,REVENDA 1,Saida
> 5,29/01/2017 08:00,REVENDA 2,Entrada
> 6,29/01/2017 10:00,REVENDA 2,Saida
> 7,29/01/2017 20:00,FABRICA,Entrada
> 8,29/01/2017 23:00,FABRICA,Saida
> ```

Uma forma de conseguir o que você quer com bastante facilidade é usar a biblioteca [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Trata-se de uma biblioteca fantástica para manipulação e análise de dados. Ela tem uma curva de aprendizado considerável, mas vale a pena. Observe que ela depende de outra biblioteca muito útil, chamada [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Usando essa biblioteca, eu preparei um exemplo bastante simples que faz o seguinte:

1. Ele lê os seus dados completos (a partir de um CSV no meu caso, mas será a partir do SQL no seu) em uma tabela (que no Pandas é um [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)).
2. Filtra as linhas da tabela de forma a obter o trajeto (saindo da fábrica e chegando na revenda desejada).
3. Calcula o tempo decorrido nesse trajeto, simplesmente subtraindo o horário de partida (valor da coluna "DATA E HORA" da última linha da sub-tabela filtrada) do horário de chegada (valor da coluna "DATA E HORA" da primeira linha da sub-tabela filtrada).
4. Repete s passos 2 e 3, mas dessa vez para a estadia (o tempo que ficou parado na revenda, considerando a chegada e a saída de lá).

Observe que tem várias simplificações nesse código, pois ele é apenas ilustrativo. Por exemplo, ele assume que só há dois registros da revenda (uma entrada e uma saída). Em casos mais complexos, você vai ter que trabalhar com os filtros para garantir que pegue os registros na ordem correta (use `tabela.index` para obter os índices e `tabela.iloc` para acessar a linha de um índice).

Por fim, o resultado é dado em uma estrutura do Pandas usada para manipular tempo decorrido (chamada [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html)). Ela armazena o tempo decorrido como a soma dos dias + segundos. Vc tem os segundos, então pra ter os tempos parciais em horas ou minutos é só fazer as divisões por 3600 ou 60 apropriadamente.

Eis o código:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def calculaTempos(tabela, nomeRevenda):

    ######################################
    # Cálculo do tempo de percurso
    ######################################

    # Debug!!!!!!
    print('Tabela completa com todos os todos os dados: \n{}\n\n'.format(tabela))
    # Debug!!!!!!

    # Busca TODAS as ocorrências de FABRICA + Saida
    filtro = (tabela['LOCAL'] == 'FABRICA') & (tabela['ENTRADA/SAIDA'] == 'Saida')
    resp = tabela[filtro]
    if resp.empty:
        return None, None

    # Por simplificação, considera como partida a primeira delas
    partida = resp.index[0]

    # Busca TODAS as ocorrências de nomeRevenda + Entrada
    filtro = (tabela['LOCAL'] == nomeRevenda) & (tabela['ENTRADA/SAIDA'] == 'Entrada')
    resp = tabela[filtro]
    if resp.empty:
        return None, None

    # Por simplificação, considera como chegada a última delas
    chegada = resp.index[len(resp)-1]

    # Filtra da tabela original os dados entre a partida e a chegada calculados
    tTrajeto = tabela[partida:chegada+1]

    # Debug!!!!!!
    print('Tabela parcial com o trajeto Fabrica->Revenda: \n{}\n\n'.format(tTrajeto))
    # Debug!!!!!!

    # O tempo de percurso é o horário de chegada (a última linha da tabela)
    # menos o horário de partida (a primeira linha da tabela)
    tempoPercurso = tTrajeto.iloc[len(tTrajeto)-1]['DATA E HORA'] - tTrajeto.iloc[0]['DATA E HORA']

    ######################################
    # Cálculo do tempo de parada
    ######################################

    # Busca TODAS as ocorrências de nomeRevenda + Saida
    filtro = (tabela['LOCAL'] == nomeRevenda) & (tabela['ENTRADA/SAIDA'] == 'Saida')
    resp = tabela[filtro]
    if resp.empty:
        return tempoPercurso, None

    # Por simplificação, considera como saída a última delas
    saida = resp.index[len(resp)-1]

    # Filtra da tabela original os dados entre a chegada e a saída calculados
    tParada = tabela[chegada:saida+1]

    # Debug!!!!!!
    print('Tabela parcial com a parada na Revenda: \n{}\n\n'.format(tParada))
    # Debug!!!!!!

    # O tempo de percurso é o horário de chegada (a última linha da tabela)
    # menos o horário de partida (a primeira linha da tabela)
    tempoParada = tParada.iloc[len(tParada)-1]['DATA E HORA'] - tParada.iloc[0]['DATA E HORA']

    return tempoPercurso, tempoParada

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def main(args):
    tabela = pd.read_csv('teste.csv')
    tabela['DATA E HORA'] = pd.to_datetime(tabela['DATA E HORA'])

    tempoPercurso, tempoParada = calculaTempos(tabela, 'REVENDA 1')

    # A estrutura Timedelta do pandas armazena tempo decorrido em dias + segundos,
    # então precisa fazer uma conversãozinha pra ter os valores separadamente.
    dias, segundos = tempoPercurso.days, tempoPercurso.seconds
    horas = segundos // 3600
    minutos = (segundos % 3600) // 60
    segundos = segundos % 60
    print('Tempo de percurso entre fábrica e revenda: {:02d} dias e {:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d} horas'.format(dias, horas, minutos, segundos))

    dias, segundos = tempoParada.days, tempoParada.seconds
    horas = segundos // 3600
    minutos = (segundos % 3600) // 60
    segundos = segundos % 60
    print('Tempo parado na revenda: {:02d} dias e {:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d} horas'.format(dias, horas, minutos, segundos))

    return 0

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

E a saída dele:

```
Tabela completa com todos os todos os dados:
   ID         DATA E HORA      LOCAL ENTRADA/SAIDA
0   1 2017-01-28 07:27:00    FABRICA       Entrada
1   2 2017-01-28 09:00:00    FABRICA         Saida
2   3 2017-01-29 00:02:00  REVENDA 1       Entrada
3   4 2017-01-29 04:00:00  REVENDA 1         Saida
4   5 2017-01-29 08:00:00  REVENDA 2       Entrada
5   6 2017-01-29 10:00:00  REVENDA 2         Saida
6   7 2017-01-29 20:00:00    FABRICA       Entrada
7   8 2017-01-29 23:00:00    FABRICA         Saida


Tabela parcial com o trajeto Fabrica->Revenda:
   ID         DATA E HORA      LOCAL ENTRADA/SAIDA
1   2 2017-01-28 09:00:00    FABRICA         Saida
2   3 2017-01-29 00:02:00  REVENDA 1       Entrada


Tabela parcial com a parada na Revenda:
   ID         DATA E HORA      LOCAL ENTRADA/SAIDA
2   3 2017-01-29 00:02:00  REVENDA 1       Entrada
3   4 2017-01-29 04:00:00  REVENDA 1         Saida


Tempo de percurso entre fábrica e revenda: 00 dias e 15:02:00 horas
Tempo parado na revenda: 00 dias e 03:58:00 horas
```

Comment: Obrigado Luiz! Em uma quantidade muito grande destes dados, usar funções do próprio SQL eu ganho desempenho?

Comment: Por nada. É quase certo que ganha sim. Primeiramente porque, por melhor que o Pandas seja, o banco de dados já é preparado para fazer esse tipo de consulta em tabelas. Em segundo lugar porque você não precisa *transmitir* entre o banco e o processo os dados de todo o trajeto. Vc basicamente só transmite o resultado. Isso faz muita diferença se o banco não está na mesma máquina e se o trajeto é longo. Em terceiro lugar, esse tipo de "lógica" geralmente é independente do uso que se vai fazer do resultado, então de um ponto de vista de modelagem pode fazer muito sentido ficar junto aos dados.

Comment: continuando... Afinal, fazendo no banco de dados você pode reutilizar a mesma lógica em diferentes aplicações, construídas em diferentes linguagens. Boa sorte! :)

Comment: Obrigado novamente, você poderia me dar o "caminho das pedras" sobre como fazer? Sei muito pouco sobre SQL, algum artigo ou alguma função que eu possa pesquisar para aprender mais por favor

Comment: Eu não manjo muito de SQL porque tô há muito tempo sem mexer com algum banco de dados relacional. Como eu disse na minha primeira observação, a sua pergunta foi aberta para Python. Talvez por isso não atraiu a atenção do pessoal que manja de SQL. Outra coisa é: qual é exatamente a sua dificuldade com o SQL? É fazer a query que traz o trajeto, ou é fazer a subtração das datas? Sugiro que vc abra outra pergunta, específica pra SQL, pedindo ajuda. Há muitas pessoas por aqui que podem te ajudar, mas a pergunta tem que ser bem feitinha.

Answer (score 0):

## Com o MySQL pode usar a função TIMESTAMPDIFF

Com esse comando `SELECT` abaixo você pode saber a quantidade de minutos entre os dois pontos. Para selecionar o ID de cada ponto, na sua interface você coloca um filtro para o usuário selecionar o Local e o Ponto de Entrada/Saída. Cada opção que você colocar para o usuário terá um ID associado que você usará de *input* para a consulta `SQL`.

No exemplo, estou admitindo como ponto de origem a saída da fábrica e como destino o ponto de entrada na revenda 2.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF ( 
    MINUTE,
    (select DATA from Tablela WHERE ID=2),
    (select DATA from Tablela WHERE ID=5)
    )
```

Resultado

```
1380 minutos
```

Você pode trocar o parâmetro `MINUTE` por `HOUR`, por exemplo, mas com minutos terá uma precisão maior que pode converter para horas decimais, se quiser.